# Преобразование String в DOM-элементы

Tags: javascript, java, html, groovy, grails

Проект на `Grails`, пишу на `Groovy`. Передаю представлению (`hello.gsp`) строку:

```
// HelloController
...
def message = <b>test</b>
...
render view: hello, model: [message: message]
```

На самой странице вызываю:
`${message}` с результатом `<b>test</b>`, что логично.
Пробую скрипт:

```
var s = '${message}';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = s;
```

и результатом вижу все то же `<b>test</b>`

Хотя, если сделать так:

`var s = '<b>test</b>'`,

то все сработает и вообще будет отлично.

В чем причина явления, как с этим бороться? Хочу запихать `html` код в `div` из контроллера, что то вроде уведомлений со ссылкой, только и всего. Шаблон на уведомления универсальный, меняется только содержимое.

Comment: 1) Вы каждый раз создаете новый div, так и должно быть?
2) А что дальше с переменной "div" происходит, вы точно её вставляете куда-то на страницу, а не "s"?
3) Если после загрузки посмотреть код страницы, то что находится в var s = 'здесь';?

Comment: Я уже сам разобрался давно, там просто grails tag парсил строку как обычный текст, а не html код. Наверное для предотвращения атак. Но у меня содержимое блока этого формируется на стороне сервера, и вообще все обращения к БД идут через gorm. Убрал ограничение и все.

Comment: @artwolf, вы можете сами опубликовать решение проблемы как ответ. Возможно, это поможет другим пользователям, оказавшимся в той же ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ, хоть и реализация сейчас у меня совсем другая. Чтобы "заработали" html-теги надо добавить атрибут `encodeAs="None"` в grails-тэг `<g:message>`

```
<g:message message="${flash.message}" encodeAs="None"/>
```

Но надо четко знать, что отправляешь в message, чтобы избежать разного рода **уязвимостей**. В моем случае это было стандартное уведомление о том, что все успешно.